# Why does C allow to return a different type than the function return type?

Tags: c, function

In this code, the multiply function's return type is char. Clearly, I'm returning a double value and printing with the double format specifier and it gives the appropriate value. If I try to print using the %c format specifier, it doesn't print anything. Either way, isn't it supposed to give an error?

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char multiply(double x, double y)
{
return (double)(x * y);
}

int main() {
    double x = 10, y = 20;
    printf("%f", multiply(x, y));
}
```

Comment: Actually, C does not allow this. The `double` value is converted to `char` before returning the value. You are invoking undefined behaviour by using `%f` for a parameter of type `int` (that is what the return type `char` is promoted to for variadic functions).

Comment: C supports implicit conversions. This one should have given a warning.  Try it with 0.1 and 0.2

Comment: If you enable compiler warnings, you would almost certainly get a warning, e.g.: `warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘double’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]`. And if you treat warnings as errors, the compiler would reject the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, C does not allow this.

> Clearly, I'm returning a double value and printing with the double format specifier and it gives the appropriate value

No, you do not return a value of type `double`.
That value is converted to `char` before the function is left.
This is called an implicit conversion.

Using format specifier `%f` requires a parameter of type `double`. Instead you pass a `char` which is promoted to `int` for variadic functions. This parameter mismatch causes undefined behaviour. If the result looks like you wanted it, that is just by accident.

> If I try to print using the %c format specifier, it doesn't print anything.

You multiple `10*20`. What result do you expect if you print the value `200`?
If your `char` is signed, then this overflows to a negative value.
That is no valid ASCII value and probably nothing that is printable.

> Either way, isn't it supposed to give an error?

At least you should get some warning.
I am not sure about the implicit conversion but surely for the parameter mismatch in `printf`.

If you did not get one, turn up warning level.
For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra`.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Yes, I got a warning. Thank you.